# Android: recommended bufferSizeInBytes value in AudioRecord

Tags: android, audiorecord

I'm using the AudioRecord class which constructor is:

```
AudioRecord(
    int audioSource, int sampleRateInHz,
    int channelConfig, int audioFormat, int bufferSizeInBytes)
```

In all (or in the most) of the tutorials and examples I find on the Internet it's recommed to set bufferSizeInBytes like follows:

```
bufferSizeInBytes= getMinBufferSize (
    int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat)
```

Could anyone tell me the reason?

I need to make the correlation between the values I'm recording and a pattern. This pattern is longer than MinBufferSize. So, should I just increase bufferSizeInBytes to the value I prefer, or is that going to worsen the performance of AudioRecord.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me the reason?

Because what `getMinBufferSize` returns for a given configuration is the smallest buffer size you'll be allowed to specify when creating you `AudioRecord`.

Why would you want the smallest possible buffer size? To get the lowest possible latency.
Imagine that you're doing something like an SPL meter; you wouldn't want there to be a one-second delay before your UI reacts to a change in the sound pressure.

The buffer size doesn't determine how much data you can request from `read()`, though. It's ok to request more data than the size of the `AudioRecord's` buffer; `read()` simply won't return until all the data you've requested has been read.

Comment: From Android AudioRecord doc page: "Data should be read from the audio hardware in chunks of sizes inferior to the total recording buffer size."